# SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, sql-injection

Is there an SQL injection possibility even when using `mysql_real_escape_string()` function?

Consider this sample situation. SQL is constructed in PHP like this:

```
$login = mysql_real_escape_string(GetFromPost('login'));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(GetFromPost('password'));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password'";
```

I have heard numerous people say to me that code like that is still dangerous and possible to hack even with `mysql_real_escape_string()` function used. But I cannot think of any possible exploit?

Classic injections like this:

```
aaa' OR 1=1 --
```

do not work.

Do you know of any possible injection that would get through the PHP code above?

Comment: Usually it's better to do the password validation in the PHP code so you can display a more verbose error (invalid user / invalid password)

Comment: @ThiefMaster I know, the above is just a simple example to get my point across.

Comment: Always use prepared statements.  The security provision, performance benefits of statement re-use, standardised coding, and library maintainance always (in my opinion) out-weigh any other alternative 'short-cut' method.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I prefer not to give verbose errors like invalid user / invalid password... it tells brute force merchants that they have a valid user ID, and it's just the password they need to guess

Comment: It's horrible from an usability point of view though. Sometimes you couldn't use your main nickname/username/email-address and forget this after some time or the site deleted your account for inactivity. Then it's extremely annoying if you continue trying passwords and maybe even get your IP blocked even though it's just your username that is invalid.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @tereško: They will not remove the mysql_* function from php, at least not very soon. Maybe in 2050. Think about it, if they remove it, all the servers that are doing automatic update of php will have all the websites nonfunctional. That's just absurd.

Comment: @machineaddict, since 5.5 (which was released recently) the `mysql_*` functions already produce `E_DEPRECATED` warning. The `ext/mysql` extension has not been maintained for more then 10 years. Are you really so delusional?

Comment: As most production websites do not print errors, E_DEPRECATED is useless. Until "all" websites switch from mysql functions, it will not be removed. Even where I work, **I have to work** with mysql extension, because even they don't think it will be removed very soon. Maybe in php 6.0. Will see...

Comment: @machineaddict It will be removed eventually. Servers don't really do automatic updates as you claimed. Most servers are running LTS versions of Linux so they are still running relatively old PHP versions (lots of servers still on PHP 5.1 or 5.2). If they remove it in the next major release of PHP, there will be enough time to stop using mysql_* functions (and seriously nobody has been using it for years, it's only in legacy code) as it will take time (probably few years) until the new release is rolled into LTS releases.

Comment: There is only one ultimate way to protect you against SQL injection. Just check the variable contains what you are expecting for. If you are expecting an integer, use ctype_digit...
IN most case you shoudl surround it with "" or ''. and escape in variable matching quotes...

Comment: A [space] character after the two dashes ( -- ) in the last may make the query valid. *aaa' OR 1=1 --[SPACE_HERE]*

Comment: @Loenix: With ints there might be an even better way than that: rather than checking, simply turn it *into* what you're expecting. `$value = (int) $value;` or `$value = intval($value);`.  It handles things like negative signs, which `ctype_digit` won't.

Comment: @cHao I can't agree with you. The best way is always to check values cause is does not mean that all integers are expected, we don't want to insert a value that the user don't want too.
If you are inserting data, you must : check the content you are expecting and format the value to be standardized or workable.
Here, if you check it and you got a non-well formated user name, you could return "Hey your value is not valid, please fix it."

Comment: @Loenix: If you're filtering for *business reasons* (eg: ensuring that a phone number looks like a phone number), that's one thing.  But filtering for technical reasons is wrongheaded. SQL injection isn't caused by bad data; it's caused by bad *code*.  One should be able to have a name of `<script>alert("①'ᆖ@\'½¶ഝ")`, if they really want to type it in.  If it would break your app, then your app is *already broken*.  At best, rejecting such a name for technical reasons is a band-aid; at worst, it's false security.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: @machineaddict They just removed that extension on PHP 7.0 and it is not 2050 yet.

Answer (score 422, accepted):

Consider the following query:

```
$iId = mysql_real_escape_string("1 OR 1=1");    
$sSql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $iId";
```

`mysql_real_escape_string()` will not protect you against this.
**The fact that you use single quotes (`' '`) around your variables inside your query is what protects you against this.** The following is also an option:

```
$iId = (int)"1 OR 1=1";
$sSql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $iId";
```

Comment: What if the users passes a single quote as part of the value: `1'; DROP TABLE --` the trailing comment will make the engine ignore the dangling other single quote from the statement

Comment: @wesley `$iId = mysql_real_escape_string((int)"1; DROP table");` or `$dirty = "1; DROP table";$iId = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$dirty); would be a better example than what you have, I think.

Comment: But this wouldn't be a real problem, because `mysql_query()` doesn't execute multiple statements, no?

Comment: @Pekka, Although the usual example is `DROP TABLE`, in practice the attacker is more likely to `SELECT passwd FROM users`. In the latter case, the second query is usually executed by use of a `UNION` clause.

Comment: `(int)mysql_real_escape_string` - this makes no sense. It doesn't differ from `(int)` at all. And they will produce the same result for every input

Comment: This is more of a misuse of the function than anything else. After all, it is named `mysql_real_escape_string`, not `mysql_real_escape_integer` . It's not mean to be used with integer fields.

Comment: @ircmaxell, Yet the answer is totally misleading. Obviously the question is asking about the **contents** within the quotes. "Quotes are not there" is **not** the answer to this question.

Comment: Why did you remove the edit, @eggyal? Casting to int will produce a number, anyway. There can be nothing dangerous about numbers related to escaping, right? And Cast to integer itself does not care about any escaping.

Comment: @wesley "The fact that you use single quotes (' ') around your variables inside your query is what protects you against this." Well but the single quotes were part of the example, the question asked for an attack for that situation, when you use single quotes.

Comment: @Wesley van Opdorp Why does single quoting protect from SQL injection? The query looks like this after expanding variables:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE login='aaa' or 1=1 --' AND password='some_value'
Why this is not a valid SQL statement?

Comment: @CuriousGuy The query would look like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE login='aaa or 1=1 --' AND password='some_value' ; your payload value is the whole term and single quotes are put around the whole term, thus it is safe.

Comment: This answer is misleading, if taken too literally. It is the *combination* of `quoting` **and** `mysql_real_escape_string` that protects you. Otherwise it is trivial to escape the quote, by providing your own quote mark. As pointed out in the very first comment on this answer!

Comment: @rndus2r - it is only safe *if you also use mysql_real_escape_string*. See the first comment on this answer, where `'` is included within the value.

Answer (score 751):

The short answer is **yes, yes there is a way to get around `mysql_real_escape_string()`**.
#For Very OBSCURE EDGE CASES!!!

The long answer isn't so easy. It's based off an attack [demonstrated here](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string).

## The Attack

So, let's start off by showing the attack...

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES gbk');
$var = mysql_real_escape_string("\xbf\x27 OR 1=1 /*");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '$var' LIMIT 1");
```

In certain circumstances, that will return more than 1 row. Let's dissect what's going on here:

1. **Selecting a Character Set**

   ```
   mysql_query('SET NAMES gbk');
   ```

   For this attack to work, we need the encoding that the server's expecting on the connection both to encode `'` as in ASCII i.e. `0x27` *and* to have some character whose final byte is an ASCII `\` i.e. `0x5c`.  As it turns out, there are 5 such encodings supported in MySQL 5.6 by default: `big5`, `cp932`, `gb2312`, `gbk` and `sjis`.  We'll select `gbk` here.

   Now, it's very important to note the use of `SET NAMES` here. This sets the character set **ON THE SERVER**. If we used the call to the C API function `mysql_set_charset()`, we'd be fine (on MySQL releases since 2006). But more on why in a minute...
2. **The Payload**

   The payload we're going to use for this injection starts with the byte sequence `0xbf27`.  In `gbk`, that's an invalid multibyte character; in `latin1`, it's the string `¿'`.  Note that in `latin1` **and** `gbk`, `0x27` on its own is a literal `'` character.

   We have chosen this payload because, if we called `addslashes()` on it, we'd insert an ASCII `\` i.e. `0x5c`, before the `'` character. So we'd wind up with `0xbf5c27`, which in `gbk` is a two character sequence: `0xbf5c` followed by `0x27`. Or in other words, a *valid* character followed by an unescaped `'`. But we're not using `addslashes()`. So on to the next step...
3. **mysql_real_escape_string()**

   The C API call to `mysql_real_escape_string()` differs from `addslashes()` in that it knows the connection character set. So it can perform the escaping properly for the character set that the server is expecting. However, up to this point, the client thinks that we're still using `latin1` for the connection, because we never told it otherwise. We did tell the *server* we're using `gbk`, but the *client* still thinks it's `latin1`.

   Therefore the call to `mysql_real_escape_string()` inserts the backslash, and we have a free hanging `'` character in our "escaped" content! In fact, if we were to look at `$var` in the `gbk` character set, we'd see:

   ```
   縗' OR 1=1 /*
   ```

   Which is [exactly what](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%B8%97%27%20OR&oq=%E7%B8%97%27%20OR&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) the attack requires.
4. **The Query**

   This part is just a formality, but here's the rendered query:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '縗' OR 1=1 /*' LIMIT 1
   ```

Congratulations, you just successfully attacked a program using `mysql_real_escape_string()`...

## The Bad

It gets worse. `PDO` defaults to *emulating* prepared statements with MySQL. That means that on the client side, it basically does a sprintf through `mysql_real_escape_string()` (in the C library), which means the following will result in a successful injection:

```
$pdo->query('SET NAMES gbk');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(array("\xbf\x27 OR 1=1 /*"));
```

Now, it's worth noting that you can prevent this by disabling emulated prepared statements:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

This will *usually* result in a true prepared statement (i.e. the data being sent over in a separate packet from the query). However, be aware that PDO will silently [fallback](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c#L210) to emulating statements that MySQL can't prepare natively: those that it can are [listed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-prepared-statements.html#prepared-statements-permitted) in the manual, but beware to select the appropriate server version).

## The Ugly

I said at the very beginning that we could have prevented all of this if we had used `mysql_set_charset('gbk')` instead of `SET NAMES gbk`. And that's true provided you are using a MySQL release since 2006.

If you're using an earlier MySQL release, then a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8378) in `mysql_real_escape_string()` meant that invalid multibyte characters such as those in our payload were treated as single bytes for escaping purposes *even if the client had been correctly informed of the connection encoding* and so this attack would still succeed.  The bug was fixed in MySQL [4.1.20](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/news-4-1-20.html), [5.0.22](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.0/en/news-5-0-22.html) and [5.1.11](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.1/en/news-5-1-11.html).

But the worst part is that `PDO` didn't expose the C API for `mysql_set_charset()` until 5.3.6, so in prior versions it **cannot** prevent this attack for every possible command!
It's now exposed as a [DSN parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php).

## The Saving Grace

As we said at the outset, for this attack to work the database connection must be encoded using a vulnerable character set.  [`utf8mb4`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) is *not vulnerable* and yet can support *every* Unicode character: so you could elect to use that instead—but it has only been available since MySQL 5.5.3.  An alternative is [`utf8`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html), which is also *not vulnerable* and can support the whole of the Unicode [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

Alternatively, you can enable the [`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) SQL mode, which (amongst other things) alters the operation of `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  With this mode enabled, `0x27` will be replaced with `0x2727` rather than `0x5c27` and thus the escaping process *cannot* create valid characters in any of the vulnerable encodings where they did not exist previously (i.e. `0xbf27` is still `0xbf27` etc.)—so the server will still reject the string as invalid.  However, see [@eggyal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23277864/623041) for a different vulnerability that can arise from using this SQL mode.

## Safe Examples

The following examples are safe:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
$var = mysql_real_escape_string("\xbf\x27 OR 1=1 /*");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '$var' LIMIT 1");
```

Because the server's expecting `utf8`...

```
mysql_set_charset('gbk');
$var = mysql_real_escape_string("\xbf\x27 OR 1=1 /*");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '$var' LIMIT 1");
```

Because we've properly set the character set so the client and the server match.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->query('SET NAMES gbk');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(array("\xbf\x27 OR 1=1 /*"));
```

Because we've turned off emulated prepared statements.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=gbk', $user, $password);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(array("\xbf\x27 OR 1=1 /*"));
```

Because we've set the character set properly.

```
$mysqli->query('SET NAMES gbk');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1');
$param = "\xbf\x27 OR 1=1 /*";
$stmt->bind_param('s', $param);
$stmt->execute();
```

Because MySQLi does true prepared statements all the time.

## Wrapping Up

If you:

- Use Modern Versions of MySQL (late 5.1, all 5.5, 5.6, etc) **AND** `mysql_set_charset()` / `$mysqli->set_charset()` / PDO's DSN charset parameter (in PHP ≥ 5.3.6)

**OR**

- Don't use a vulnerable character set for connection encoding (you only use `utf8` / `latin1` / `ascii` / etc)

You're 100% safe.

Otherwise, you're vulnerable **even though you're using `mysql_real_escape_string()`**...

Comment: PDO emulating prepare statements for MySQL, really? I don't see any reason why it would do that since the driver supports it natively. No?

Comment: It does. They say in the documentation it doesn't. But in the source code, it's plainly visible and easy to fix. I chalk it up to incompetence of the devs.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith: It's not that easy to fix. I've been working on changing the default, but it fails a boat load of tests when switched. So it's a bigger change than it seems. I'm still hoping to have it finished by 5.5...

Comment: @ircmaxell There are few things: as stated in the article You link to, this vulnerability could be used only when using `addslashes()` and not `mysql_real_escape_string()` - that should be safe, as written in the article (read once more). Secondly I am very curious how could one PUT, GET or POST `char(0xBF)` followed by `char(0x27)`...Though it could be demonstrated with ourselves written PHP I doubt one could post such values from a form or an URL...

Comment: @shadyyx: No, the vulnerability the article described was about `addslashes`. I **based** this vulnerability on that one. Try it yourself. Go get MySQL 5.0, and run this exploit and see for yourself. As far as how to put that into PUT/GET/POST, it's TRIVIAL. Input data are just byte streams. `char(0xBF)` is just a readable way of generating a byte. I've demoed this vulnerability live in front of multiple conferences. Trust me on this... But if you don't, try it yourself. It works...

Comment: @shadyyx: As for passing such funkiness in $\_GET... `?var=%BF%27+OR+1=1+%2F%2A` in the URL, `$var = $_GET['var'];` in the code, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: @MarkAmery: On reflection, I think you're right.  If I want to send `0xbf27` i.e. `¿'` over a `latin1` connection then of course the client **must** still escape it as `¿\'` i.e. `0xbf5c27`. However, if the server is decoding received bytes using GBK (i.e. the client was mistaken about the connection's encoding) then it will perceive there to be an unescaped `'` and cannot have any way of knowing that wasn't the developer's intended SQL. I have updated this answer with what I think had been intended: prior to the bugfix, even correctly setting the client charset wouldn't help!

Comment: @eggyal I now understand the issue properly (and have reproduced it just for fun). Thank you for your awesome work here. Additional things that may be worth noting: 1. the same attack can be demonstrated against `mysqli_real_escape_string` (as one would expect); your brief note about MySQLi here could be interpreted by somebody foolish as meaning that MySQLi is immune to this attack, but that's only true if you use parametrized queries. 2. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php hints at this attack's existence and describes proper ways to set connection charset for each API.

Comment: I have a feeling that some emphasizings should be removed, and a cool headed TL;DR added, saying that as long as encoding is set properly and single quotes are used, there would be not a single problem.

Comment: Is the charset still an issue? Because on the `php-5.6.1` tag, the description of `mysql_real_escape_strings` states that `Escape special characters in a string for use in a SQL statement, taking into account the current charset of the connection` so I suppose it depends how the "current charset of the connection" is determined.

Comment: Does modern PDO still default to emulating escaping? That's terrifying if so.

Comment: I didn't change the default charset when using mysql in hostgator.  does that mean because it was an american based hosting they would have set the default charset to utf8 and I am safe?

Answer (score 208):

> ## TL;DR
>
> `mysql_real_escape_string()` will **provide no protection whatsoever** (and could furthermore munge your data) if:
>
> - MySQL's [`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) SQL mode is enabled (which it *might* be, unless you *explicitly* select another SQL mode *every time you connect*); and
> - your SQL string literals are quoted using double-quote `"` characters.
>
> This was filed as [bug #72458](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72458) and has been fixed in MySQL v5.7.6 (see the section headed "**The Saving Grace**", below).

## This is another, (perhaps less?) obscure EDGE CASE!!!

In homage to [@ircmaxell's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602) (really, this is supposed to be flattery and not plagiarism!), I will adopt his format:

### The Attack

Starting off with a demonstration...

```php
mysql_query('SET SQL_MODE="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES"'); // could already be set
$var = mysql_real_escape_string('" OR 1=1 -- ');
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = "'.$var.'" LIMIT 1');
```

This will return all records from the `test` table.  A dissection:

1. **Selecting an SQL Mode**

   ```php
   mysql_query('SET SQL_MODE="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES"');
   ```

   As documented under [String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html):

   > There are several ways to include quote characters within a string:
   >
   > - A “`'`” inside a string quoted with “`'`” may be written as “`''`”.
   > - A “`"`” inside a string quoted with “`"`” may be written as “`""`”.
   > - Precede the quote character by an escape character (“`\`”).
   > - A “`'`” inside a string quoted with “`"`” needs no special treatment and need not be doubled or escaped. In the same way, “`"`” inside a string quoted with “`'`” needs no special treatment.

   If the server's SQL mode includes [`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes), then the third of these options—which is the usual approach adopted by `mysql_real_escape_string()`—is not available: one of the first two options must be used instead.  Note that the effect of the fourth bullet is that one must necessarily know the character that will be used to quote the literal in order to avoid munging one's data.
2. **The Payload**

   ```php
   " OR 1=1 --
   ```

   The payload initiates this injection quite literally with the `"` character.  No particular encoding.  No special characters.  No weird bytes.
3. **mysql_real_escape_string()**

   ```php
   $var = mysql_real_escape_string('" OR 1=1 -- ');
   ```

   Fortunately, `mysql_real_escape_string()` does check the SQL mode and adjust its behaviour accordingly.  See [`libmysql.c`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/libmysql/1.0/view/head:/libmysql/libmysql.c#L1267):

   ```c
   ulong STDCALL
   mysql_real_escape_string(MYSQL *mysql, char *to,const char *from,
                ulong length)
   {
     if (mysql->server_status & SERVER_STATUS_NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES)
       return escape_quotes_for_mysql(mysql->charset, to, 0, from, length);
     return escape_string_for_mysql(mysql->charset, to, 0, from, length);
   }
   ```

   Thus a different underlying function, `escape_quotes_for_mysql()`, is invoked if the `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` SQL mode is in use.  As mentioned above, such a function needs to know which character will be used to quote the literal in order to repeat it without causing the other quotation character from being repeated literally.

   However, this function arbitrarily *assumes* that the string will be quoted using the single-quote `'` character.  See [`charset.c`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/libmysql/1.0/view/head:/mysys/charset.c#L836):

   ```c
   /*
     Escape apostrophes by doubling them up

   // [ deletia 839-845 ]

     DESCRIPTION
       This escapes the contents of a string by doubling up any apostrophes that
       it contains. This is used when the NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES SQL_MODE is in
       effect on the server.

   // [ deletia 852-858 ]
   */

   size_t escape_quotes_for_mysql(CHARSET_INFO *charset_info,
                                  char *to, size_t to_length,
                                  const char *from, size_t length)
   {
   // [ deletia 865-892 ]

       if (*from == '\'')
       {
         if (to + 2 > to_end)
         {
           overflow= TRUE;
           break;
         }
         *to++= '\'';
         *to++= '\'';
       }
   ```

   So, it leaves double-quote `"` characters untouched (and doubles all single-quote `'` characters) *irrespective of the actual character that is used to quote the literal*!  In our case `$var` remains exactly the same as the argument that was provided to `mysql_real_escape_string()`—it's as though no escaping has taken place *at all*.
4. **The Query**

   ```php
   mysql_query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = "'.$var.'" LIMIT 1');
   ```

   Something of a formality, the rendered query is:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = "" OR 1=1 -- " LIMIT 1
   ```

As my learned friend put it: congratulations, you just successfully attacked a program using `mysql_real_escape_string()`...

### The Bad

[`mysql_set_charset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) cannot help, as this has nothing to do with character sets; nor can [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), since that's just a different wrapper around this same function.

The problem, if not already obvious, is that the call to `mysql_real_escape_string()` **cannot know** with which character the literal will be quoted, as that's left to the developer to decide at a later time.  So, in `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` mode, there is literally *no way* that this function can safely escape every input for use with arbitrary quoting (at least, not without doubling characters that do not require doubling and thus munging your data).

### The Ugly

It gets worse.  `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` may not be all that uncommon in the wild owing to the necessity of its use for compatibility with standard SQL (e.g. see section 5.3 of the [SQL-92 specification](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), namely the `<quote symbol> ::= <quote><quote>` grammar production and lack of any special meaning given to backslash).  Furthermore, its use was explicitly [recommended as a workaround](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.1/en/news-5-1-11.html) to the (long since fixed) [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8378) that ircmaxell's post describes.  Who knows, some DBAs might even configure it to be on by default as means of discouraging use of incorrect escaping methods like [`addslashes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).

Also, the [SQL mode of a new connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting) is set by the server according to its configuration (which a `SUPER` user can change at any time); thus, to be certain of the server's behaviour, you must *always* explicitly specify your desired mode after connecting.

### The Saving Grace

So long as you always *explicitly* set the SQL mode not to include `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`, or quote MySQL string literals using the single-quote character, this bug cannot rear its ugly head: respectively `escape_quotes_for_mysql()` will not be used, or its assumption about which quote characters require repeating will be correct.

For this reason, I recommend that anyone using `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` also enables [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) mode, as it will force habitual use of single-quoted string literals.  Note that this does not prevent SQL injection in the event that double-quoted literals happen to be used—it merely reduces the likelihood of that happening (because normal, non-malicious queries would fail).

In PDO, both its equivalent function [`PDO::quote()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) and its prepared statement emulator call upon [`mysql_handle_quoter()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c#L302)—which does exactly this: it ensures that the escaped literal is quoted in single-quotes, so you can be certain that PDO is always immune from this bug.

As of MySQL v5.7.6, this bug has been fixed.  See [change log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-6.html):

> #### Functionality Added or Changed
>
> - ***Incompatible Change:*** A new C API function, [`mysql_real_escape_string_quote()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string-quote.html), has been implemented as a replacement for [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) because the latter function can fail to properly encode characters when the [`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) SQL mode is enabled. In this case, [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) cannot escape quote characters except by doubling them, and to do this properly, it must know more information about the quoting context than is available. [`mysql_real_escape_string_quote()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string-quote.html) takes an extra argument for specifying the quoting context. For usage details, see [mysql_real_escape_string_quote()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string-quote.html).
>
>   > #### Note
>   >
>   > Applications should be modified to use [`mysql_real_escape_string_quote()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string-quote.html), instead of [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html), which now fails and produces an [`CR_INSECURE_API_ERR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-client.html#error_cr_insecure_api_err) error if [`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) is enabled.
>
>   References: See also Bug #19211994.

### Safe Examples

Taken together with the bug explained by ircmaxell, the following examples are entirely safe (assuming that one is either using MySQL later than 4.1.20, 5.0.22, 5.1.11; or that one is not using a GBK/Big5 connection encoding):

```php
mysql_set_charset($charset);
mysql_query("SET SQL_MODE=''");
$var = mysql_real_escape_string('" OR 1=1 /*');
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = "'.$var.'" LIMIT 1');
```

...because we've explicitly selected an SQL mode that doesn't include `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`.

```php
mysql_set_charset($charset);
$var = mysql_real_escape_string("' OR 1=1 /*");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = '$var' LIMIT 1");
```

...because we're quoting our string literal with single-quotes.

```php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(["' OR 1=1 /*"]);
```

...because PDO prepared statements are immune from this vulnerability (and ircmaxell's too, provided either that you're using PHP≥5.3.6 and the character set has been correctly set in the DSN; or that prepared statement emulation has been disabled).

```php
$var  = $pdo->quote("' OR 1=1 /*");
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = $var LIMIT 1");
```

...because PDO's `quote()` function not only escapes the literal, but also quotes it (in single-quote `'` characters); note that to avoid ircmaxell's bug in this case, you *must* be using PHP≥5.3.6 *and* have correctly set the character set in the DSN.

```php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1');
$param = "' OR 1=1 /*";
$stmt->bind_param('s', $param);
$stmt->execute();
```

...because MySQLi prepared statements are safe.

### Wrapping Up

Thus, if you:

- use native prepared statements

**OR**

- use MySQL v5.7.6 or later

**OR**

- in *addition* to employing one of the solutions in ircmaxell's summary, use at least one of:

  - PDO;
  - single-quoted string literals; or
  - an explicitly set SQL mode that does not include `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`

...then you *should* be completely safe (vulnerabilities outside the scope of string escaping aside).

Comment: So, TL;DR would be like "there is a NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mysql server mode which can cause an injection if you aren't using single quotes.

Comment: I'm not able to access http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72458; I just get an access denied page. Is it being hidden from the public due to being a security issue? Also, do I understand correctly from this answer that you are the discoverer of the vulnerability? If so, congratulations.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Er, I think the answer to both of those questions is "yes" - although I suspect many won't consider this to be a vulnerability *per se*, but rather a design flaw in separating escaping from quoting.  In the bug report I have proposed a fix, but as it changes the protocol (albeit in a safe way) I don't know whether the fix will be adopted.

Comment: People shouldn't be using `"` for strings in the first place.  SQL says that's for identifiers.  But eh...just another example of MySQL saying "screw standards, i'll do whatever i want".  (Fortunately, you can include `ANSI_QUOTES` in the mode to fix the quoting brokenness.  The open disregard of standards, though, is a bigger issue that might require more severe measures.)

Comment: @eggyal, is using PDO sufficient, or is it necessary to use PDO prepared statements?  Consider this in php/PDO: $sql="select * from product_master where abbr='".$_GET['prod']."'";// order by skey limit ".mt_rand(1,10).", 10"; $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);  That would be wide open to injection, with no protection on the $_GET. No?  Also, use of single quotes needs to be supported with mysqli_real_escape_string, is that right? If these questions seem too obvious, my problem is that I am reading the answer and I am not certain it says these things flat out. I can see the examples show this.

Comment: @DanAllen: my answer was a little broader, in that you *can* avoid *this particular* bug through PDO's `quote()` function—but prepared statements are a much safer and more appropriate way to avoid injection generally.  Of course, if you have directly concatenated unescaped variables into your SQL then you are most certainly vulnerable to injection no matter what methods you use thereafter.

Comment: @eggyall: Our system relies on the 2nd safe example above. There are errors, where mysql_real_escape_string has been omitted. Fixing those in an emergency mode seems to be the prudent path, hoping we don't get nuked before the corrections.  My rationale is converting to prepared statements will be a much longer process that will have to come after. Is the reason prepared statements is safer the fact that errors don't create vulnerabilities? In other words, is correctly implemented 2nd example above is  just as safe as prepared statements?

Comment: Nice breakdown.. i assume `mysql->charset` within the functions `escape_quotes_for_mysql(mysql->charset, to, 0, from, length)` and `escape_string_for_mysql(mysql->charset, to, 0, from, length);` is MySQL's default connecting charset or if used `SET NAMES ` or anny kind of `set_charset()` function?

Comment: @eggyal,If I set `sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`.Is that safe enough? Need I additional use `mysql_query("SET SQL_MODE=''");` in PHP script?

Comment: @kittygirl - you've got it backwards. This answer says "NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES" is *dangerous* (unless you do one of the other suggestions, to avoid the danger). You show an sql_mode that *includes* "NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES". You just took an unnecessary risk - remove that.

Answer (score 22):

Well, there's nothing really that can pass through that, other than `%` wildcard. It could be dangerous if you were using `LIKE` statement as attacker could put just `%` as login if you don't filter that out, and would have to just bruteforce a password of any of your users.
People often suggest using prepared statements to make it 100% safe, as data can't interfere with the query itself that way.
But for such simple queries it probably would be more efficient to do something like `$login = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $login);`

Comment: +1, but the wildcards are for LIKE clause, not simple equality.

Comment: By what measure do you consider a simple replacement `more efficient` than using prepared statements?  (Prepared statements always work, the library can be quickly corrected in case of attacks, doesn't expose human error [such as mis-typing the complete replace string], and have significant performance benefits if the statement is re-used.)

Comment: @Slava: You're effectively limiting usernames and passwords to word chars only.  Most people who know anything about security would consider that a bad idea, as it shrinks the search space considerably.  Course they'd also consider it a bad idea to store cleartext passwords in the database, but we don't need to be compounding the problem.  :)

Comment: @cHao, my suggestion concerns only logins. Obviously you don't need to filter passwords, sorry it isn't clearly stated in my answer. But actually that might be good idea. Using "stone ignorant tree space" instead of hard-to-remember-and-type "a4üua3!@v\"ä90;8f" would be much harder to bruteforce. Even using a dictionary of, say 3000 words to help you, knowing you used exactly 4 words - that would still be roughly 3.3*10^12 combinations. :)

Comment: @Slava: I've seen that idea before; see http://xkcd.com/936/ .  Problem is, the math doesn't quite bear it out.  Your example 17-char password would have like 96^17 possibilities, and that's if you forgot the umlauts and limited yourself to printable ASCII.  That's about 4.5x10^33.  We're talking literally *a billion trillion times* more work to brute force.  Even an 8-char ASCII password would have 7.2x10^15 possibilities -- 3 thousand times more.

Comment: @cHao, sorry to go on with this holy war here, but still... Let's say you're pretty good on resources and can try 100 million passwords/sec. Using 3k-words dictionary and knowing there are 4 words trying 3.3 trillion passwords would take you about 23 days. That will be enough for host to notice stolen DB and change your password. Safe enough. You can make that many times harder by alternating lower/upper-case letters. And all this assuming attacker knows there are exactly 4 words, which is unlikely.

Comment: And if you use self-made words, leaving attacker with need to try by char... 22 chars with 6 bits/char (lower-upper case, dashes, etc. = roughly 64) ~= 5.4 duodecillion = years

Comment: @Slava: Most site owners hardly even realize there are server logs, much less read through them. And a non-idiot attacker wouldn't *steal* the data, but simply *copy* it...leaving the site functional and your average owner not even realizing there was an intrusion (and thus, not knowing to reset passwords), giving the attacker lots of time to crack the easy phrases. Human nature effectively guarantees there will be easy phrases, especially if dictionary words are allowed. And without dictionary words, all you've done is require a 20+-character password, which the users would hate you for.  :)

Comment: Users just want to get shit done.  Security directly opposes that in most cases, and you can safely assume it will be avoided or subverted by any means possible.  People aren't going to pick a half dozen random imaginary words; they're going to pick a short line/sentence/catchphrase from their favorite book or movie or whatever, making the phrase much, much more predictable.  In order to prevent them from doing such things, you'd basically have to make the server understand English and/or search a database of most known artistic works for the phrase used.

Comment: @Slava - *Of course* if you use/require a *sufficiently long* password, it can't be guessed by brute force in reasonable amount of time. But its a bad idea to *force* that on the user, because it requires significantly more characters to be safe. An attacker will know that you've only allowed lower-case letters plus space - 27 possibilities per character. So 27^n for n characters. Contrast this with allowing people to put any character in they want. Now each typed character could be *any unicode character*. 1000000^n. ONE rare unicode char in a longer string = safe yet short password.

Comment: ... (Its the only time I've seen xkcd overlook psychology, and hence draw the wrong statistical conclusion. A smart brute-force attacker would analyze the available large dictionary of broken passwords, and draw conclusions about the distribution of character combinations to use. Of course xkcd's 4 word phrase is long enough - but so are many other strategies, that result in *much* shorter, yet memorable, passwords, which are just as difficult for a "smart brute-force" approach to break.)